# How to increase apache superset capabilities it is dying while showing more than 100K rows

Tags: apache-superset

I've tried all those things but apache superset table vizualisation dies while trying to vizualise more than 100k in a table.

Can you help what to do???

I don't really think it's hard query just easy select nothing complicated i need it for business to export as csv.
Please Help!

I've tried this but nothing helps:
[I've tried ])(https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Mch.png)

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].